# Can I filter a list of velocities(from some sources like a RADAR) using butterworth filter?

Tags: c++, filter, signal-processing

I have to implement ButterWorth filtering for the accelerations received from the RADAR in my project using C++.

I understood the Butterworth filter will filter out the frequencies but quite not sure how it will filter the data set(an array of data). Assume that we already have cutoff frequency fc and sampled frequency fs.

Thank you.

Comment: A filter does not know (and does not care) about the unit of your values. If you use a low-pass filter it will filter out high frequencies, e.g., fast changes in the signal. Changes in a list of velocities is acceleration. So, it will filter out high acceleration, it smooths the velocity.

Comment: How is this a c++ question?

Comment: @stackoverblown, I have updated the the project language in the question, Thanks.

Comment: @mch : Butterworth filter seems to filter only the frequencies but not the actual values right, What I have now is a list of velocities(I get them from sensors), How ButterWorth filter or any filter will function in that case? I thank you for your response.

Comment: A filter works on the values in the time domain (in your case velocities) to apply the transfer function in the frequency domain (changes of the signal, in your case change of velocity ==> acceleration). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter